# The textView in RecyclerView in a Fragment, Doesn't Display Any Texts from Java or From XML Files

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Edited my question Title
I'm trying to pass JSON data into a RecyclerView that's built in a fragment, and I actually did it BEFORE I decorated the RecyclerView's list_items.xml.

Now I'm trying to display some normal texts into this Recycler View, and the AS always give me a NullPointerException at the line of MyViewHolder...after I commented the line, the app runs but the RecyclerView doesn't display any texts even the texts in the RecyclerView's list_items.xml

Here is the result I have so far, the recyclerView displayes ImageView ONLY.
And the textView doesn't work.

[image]

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private Context context; private List<ForumsListItem> forumsListItems;
ForumsFragment fragment=new ForumsFragment();
//Define the constructor for both contenxt and listItem
public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<ForumsListItem> items) {
    this.context = context;
    forumsListItems =items;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.forums_listitems,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

/*Bind everything from te MyViewHolder*/
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Define listItem position
    ForumsListItem listItem=forumsListItems.get(position);

    //Calling the textView inside bindingViewHolder
    //holder.catListName.setText(listItem.getCatlistName());
    holder.numOfDailyNewPosts.setText(listItem.getNumOftodayPosts());
    holder.descriptTv.setText(listItem.getDescription());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return forumsListItems.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements  View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView nameTv,descriptTv,numOfDailyNewPosts,catListName;

    private ImageView imgIcons;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //things to display in form of List

        descriptTv=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail);
        catListName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.catListTxt);
        numOfDailyNewPosts=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.numOfDailyNewPosts);
        //can add Picaso loding images here
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        int pos=getAdapterPosition();
        //get the current position

        ForumsListItem items= forumsListItems.get(pos);

        Toast.makeText(context,items.getForumsTitles(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //On click functionality

    }
}
```

}

My list_items.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_compat_inset_shadow"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:padding="16dp" >
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_light_yellow">
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/forumsTitleImg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/numOfDailyNewPosts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="fdlksfjsdlkjf"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/forumsTitleImg"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/item_detail"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frame"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> > 06-03 23:07:30.752 2964-2964/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
> >           06-03 23:07:30.930 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
> >     06-03 23:07:31.416 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
> >     06-03 23:07:31.493 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
> >     06-03 23:07:31.594 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
> >     06-03 23:07:31.666 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
> >     06-03 23:07:31.738 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
> >     06-03 23:07:31.913 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
> >     06-03 23:07:31.957 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
> >     06-03 23:07:32.037 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
> >     06-03 23:07:32.203 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
> >     06-03 23:07:32.324 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
> >     06-03 23:07:32.326 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen-2/lib/arm
> >     06-03 23:07:32.331 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
> >     06-03 23:07:32.571 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
> >     06-03 23:07:32.603 2964-3043/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
> >     06-03 23:07:32.662 2964-3043/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen I/Adreno-EGL: : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.3_RB1__release_AU (I741a3d36ca)
> >         OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.29.00.00
> >         Build Date: 04/04/16 Mon
> >         Local Branch: mybranch19053788
> >         Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.3_rb1.12
> >         Local Patches: NONE
> >         Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
> >     06-03 23:07:32.677 2964-3043/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
> >     06-03 23:07:32.863 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1c32706 time:11829580
> >     06-03 23:07:36.591 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen time:11833307
> >     06-03 23:07:37.435 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen D/TEST2: 10
> >     06-03 23:07:37.460 2964-3123/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/tcmclient.jar
> >     06-03 23:07:37.692 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
> >     06-03 23:07:37.773 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen I/Choreographer: Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
> >     06-03 23:07:37.980 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
> >     06-03 23:07:38.084 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
> >     06-03 23:07:38.112 2964-2964/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@b5d7e1c time:11834828
> >     06-03 23:07:38.672 2964-3123/com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Index 2 out of range [0..2)
> >             at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:293)
> >             at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:521)
> >             at com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen.ForumsFragment$ForumsJSONParser.doInBackground(ForumsFragment.java:150)
> >             at com.yamibo.bbs.splashscreen.ForumsFragment$ForumsJSONParser.doInBackground(ForumsFragment.java:126)
> >             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
> >             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: where is view of this `R.id.catListTxt` in xml??

Comment: Can you add the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kira :

Please replace your list_items.xml file with below code and check again:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/forumsTitleImg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/numOfDailyNewPosts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="fdlksfjsdlkjf" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView></RelativeLayout>
```

and Here is the Java file with static data:

```
    public class SampleActivity extends Activity{
    RecyclerView sampleRecycle;
    MyRecyclerAdapter myRecyclerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_activity);

        sampleRecycle = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.sampleRecycle);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        sampleRecycle.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        myRecyclerAdapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(this);
        sampleRecycle.setAdapter(myRecyclerAdapter);
    }


    public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        private Context context;
//        private List<ForumsListItem> forumsListItems;
//        ForumsFragment fragment = new ForumsFragment();

        //Define the constructor for both contenxt and listItem
        public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
//            forumsListItems = items;

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(v);
        }

        /*Bind everything from te MyViewHolder*/
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            //Define listItem position
//            ForumsListItem listItem = forumsListItems.get(position);

            //Calling the textView inside bindingViewHolder
            //holder.catListName.setText(listItem.getCatlistName());
//            holder.numOfDailyNewPosts.setText(listItem.getNumOftodayPosts());
//            holder.descriptTv.setText(listItem.getDescription());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 20;
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            private TextView nameTv, descriptTv, numOfDailyNewPosts, catListName;

            private ImageView imgIcons;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                //things to display in form of List

                descriptTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail);
//                catListName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.catListTxt);
                numOfDailyNewPosts = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numOfDailyNewPosts);
                //can add Picaso loding images here
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                //get the current position

//                ForumsListItem items = forumsListItems.get(pos);

//                Toast.makeText(context, items.getForumsTitles(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //On click functionality

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. but just to mention that I tested textView widget in a new Fragment, and it displayed nothing

Comment: I tried with this code, and it display the same, only imageView, no texts

Comment: @Kira can you please put the image of actual result what you want.
and also check my edited answer

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/443875131312308244/453080598584623131/unknown.png So here is what I have so far with the code above

Comment: @Kira You has initialized the ForumsFragement but you didn't used that fragment in the adapter. and why you use sampleRecycle.xml in  layout inflater instead of that layout you have to use this ***list_items.xml*** layout in inflator.

Comment: @Kira where you assign this id in xml file: ***catListTxt*** i didn't found this id into your xml

Comment: this id was for another xml FIle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172375/discussion-between-mahesh-keshvala-and-kira-nofans).